# Visual Studio Code: unable to open Git repository in on-prem DevOps

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I am able to open a GIT repository on our on-prem DevOps using the browser, but when trying to clone using VSC I get a prompt for destination folder and for credentials (good!) and then this error.

```
git clone https://******/tfs/KIT%20Testonly/KIT%20Testonly%20Git/team d:\M2Dev\GitTest\ --progress
fatal: repository 'https://******/tfs/KIT%20Testonly/KIT%20Testonly%20Git/' not found
```

I tried a few variants like suffixing /team but that makes no difference.

[image: VSC error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#get-the-clone-url-to-your-repo), you need to obtain the git clone URL from the web page, **not the browser's address bar**.

> [image] [image]

<sup>Image from Microsoft</sup>